# Query about variable selection in Random Forest

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, random-forest

I have a small doubt about variable selection in Random forest. I am aware of the fact that it chooses "m" random variables out of "M" variables for splitting and keeps the value (m) constant throughout.

My question is why these m variables are not same at each node. What is the reason behind it? Can someone help on this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Fact that it is using different set (randomly chosen) of m features for each tree is actually advantage for RF.  That way final model is more robust and accurate.  It also helps in identifying which features are contributing most and have best predictive power.
btw that's why it is called **Random** Forest after all...